# Disable Custom JavaScript Button after one click to prevent code execution multiple times

Tags: apex

The situation is, I am having a Custom JS button on Case named as 'Submit' which executes an apex class when it is clicked. The Apex class has heavy business logic and an inner Queueable class which I am using to integrate with a third party vendor. I am having a field on Case called 'Submit Successful' which is updated inside the Apex class, based on which I have implemented a logic in Submit button to show error message if Submit Successful field for the case is true.

Problem here is, If I click my Submit button more than once in a short span of time, the code is executed multiple times. I am trying to find a way to stop this behaviour and to allow the code to be executed only once.

Any solution will be of great help.

Comment: I believe the standard solution for this issue is to apply "debouncing" in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the button by doing something like this,

Once the button is clicked, user will have to wait for 3 seconds before they can click the button again.

This is just an example, to set a 3 seconds timeout, before letting the user click the button again. Perhaps, you can also **await the Apex process to complete** instead of setting a 3 seconds timeout and then make the button available for click again.

JS

```
buttonstatus = false;
async handleClick(){
    console.log('Clicked');
    this.buttonstatus = true;
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))
    this.buttonstatus = false;
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <lightning-button label="Click me" onclick={handleClick} disabled={buttonstatus}>
    </lightning-button>
    <template lwc:if={buttonstatus}>
        Process captured. Please wait for the process to complete before click the button again.
    </template>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

This will make sure, user can only click the button once and then again after 3 seconds or after all the backend logic is completed.

Of course the implementation is your choice :)

Edit:
I have edited the HTML code, to include a message, to notify the user that the button has been clicked. This will make sure user know that their click is captured.

Hope it helps!